# Using ArcGIS Python API, how can I share all items in a specific group from ArcGIS online with the public?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

I'm completely new at programming. As an administrator, I need to update items in an ArcGIS Online group to be shared with everyone. I'm building the script in Jupyter notebook. I found the below link on arcig python api page, and I've been able to get the items from the group, but I don't know how to loop and update the share of each item in the group. https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-managing-groups/

Comment: Are you wanting to change the owner?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a content search for the items and you can use the [share](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.share) method. This is not tested but should work.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
ago_gis = GIS()
webmaps = ago_gis.content.search("My Web Map", item_type="Web Map")
for x in webmaps:
    x.share(everyone=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking to do something similar but found that I had to use the share method carefully. The share method has default values of False for the 'everyone' and 'org' parameters. If you do not specify them, they default to False or do not share with everyone / do not share with my org.

In my case, I was trying to share an item with a group I made so I used the share method and only passed it the group argument. While it shared it with the intended group, it used the default values of the optional arguments 'everyone' and 'org' which set the items to only be viewed by the 'owner'. This broke any public facing apps and maps which this item was a part of.

In order to modify only the group setting, I needed to call for the item's current sharing settings (using the shared_with property), modify them as needed, and pass them into the share method with the modifications. This allowed me to keep them shared with the public or my org, but also add them to the group I needed them added to.

Here's the code I used in my notebook:

```
item_sharing_status = item.shared_with

item.share(everyone = item_sharing_status['everyone'],
           org = item_sharing_status['org'],
            groups = item_sharing_status['groups'] + [backup_group.id])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the items to share in a list with :

```
gis.content.share_items(items=[item1, item2, item3], everyone=True, org=True)
```

[link to the doc](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.ContentManager.share_items)